# Stackdriver python log RPC error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am having a RPC issue with logging an error to GCP StackDriver. Following is the error message:

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, Deadline Exceeded)>
```

Here is the python code for logging:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import config
import google.cloud.logging as gcp_logging
from google.oauth2 import service_account

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
## using Google Stackdriver logging
#client = gcp_logging.Client(project=config.project, credentials=config.credentials_gcp_ml)
#client = gcp_logging.Client.from_service_account_json('./cred.json')
cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('./cred.json')
client = gcp_logging.Client(project = config.project, credentials=cred)
hdlr = client.get_default_handler()
logger = logging.getLogger('cloudLogger')

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s  %(levelname)s   %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

I run this code in my local computer connecting to my GCP account.

```
google-auth 1.2.0; google-cloud-logging 1.4.0
```

Comment: My version of google-auth is 1.3.0 and I am using [this code](https://pastebin.com/yDstN38r), which is based on yours. Everything works fine.

Comment: Could your code on one of your instances in Compute Engine or run it in Cloud Shell? By the way this is [the error](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/ed98c2de04b8aff3c4afcfce4db29317904b59ce/google/rpc/code.proto#L61-L68) you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried your code (slightly modified to adapt it to my project, and with a last line added in order to output logs to the [Stackdriver Logging console](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs)) and it is working for me.

Here I share the code I have used:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import google.cloud.logging as gcp_logging
from google.oauth2 import service_account

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('./private-key.json')
client = gcp_logging.Client(project = "<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>", credentials=cred)
hdlr = client.get_default_handler()
logger = logging.getLogger('cloudLogger')

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s  %(levelname)s   %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info('This is a Logging Test.')
```

And after running the command `python test.py` in my local machine, this is the result I obtain:

```
Program shutting down, attempting to send 1 queued log entries to Stackdriver Logging...
Waiting up to 5 seconds.
Sent all pending logs.
```

Then, if I move to the console link I provided before and filter using the Global resource type (`resource.type="global"`), this is what I see:

[image]

As stated by @A.Queue, I am also running `google-auth` version `1.3.0` and `google-cloud-logging` `1.4.0`, so you should try upgrading `google-auth`, using the command:

```
pip install --upgrade google-auth
```

Try that and come back to us if the same error keeps coming up.

Comment: I couldn't find my logs under my VM, however, I found them in global. Is there no way to show the logs for the specific VM under the VM name?